# Is it possible to have a CASE WHEN THEN SELECT in a WHERE CLAUSE

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, where-clause

I was just wondering if it would be possible to have a CASE statement in a WHERE clause exactly in this form...

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLEA
WHERE date between '2014-02-01' and '2014-02-28' and
CASE
   WHEN date>'2014-02-28' THEN (SELECT FROM TABLEC WHERE...)
   ELSE (SELECT FROM TABLE B WHERE...)
END
```

Thanks!

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** - it can return literal values or SQL variables - but it **cannot** execute code (like a `SELECT` statement) to return something ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is possible under the following circumstances:

1. The subqueries are returning one value.
2. There is an outside comparison such as `=` or `>`

The `case` statement returns scalar values.  A row with one column and one value is "equivalent" to a scalar value.  So, the following would be allowed:

```
where col = (CASE WHEN date > '2014-02-28' THEN (SELECT max(col2) FROM TABLEC WHERE...)
                 ELSE (SELECT min(col3) FROM TABLE B WHERE...)
             END)
```

But, you probably want to do a conditional `in` statement.  Eschew the `case`:

```
where date > '2014-02-28' and col in (SELECT max(col2) FROM TABLEC WHERE...) or
      date <= '2014-02-28' and col in (SELECT min(col3) FROM TABLE B WHERE...)
```